How long is an Olympic sailing race?
What is the distance in metres of the various sailing events at the Olympic games? Also, how many laps are there in each race? For some reason this information is not readily available.

I believe sailing races don't have "laps" - my understanding is that they're always point-to-point.

@F1Krazy: I don't know specifically about the Olympics, but sailing in general has changed a lot in order to make it more spectator and television friendly. The America's Cup, for example, has turned from an open ocean race to racing practically inside the harbor doing 6 legs on a simple 1.5nm windward-leeward course. This means the spectators can be a lot closer to the course, they don't even need to be on a boat, necessarily, and they see the boats go by six times instead of just once. And it's a lot easier to beam a TV signal from a helicopter to a TV truck in the harbor as well.

@F1Krazy - they can be point-to-point.  But, even aside being more spectator-friendly, laps are often more practical. Using laps allows you to run a much longer course on a smaller patch of water, and it also makes it easier to finish races early if the wind conditions change or - at club level - if you have a mix of boat classes in the same race. The fact that you're going back to the start also makes it easier to set a course that has all points of sail (rather than, say, one very long reach) which you need to do to keep things competitive.

The different sailing classes have a particular amount of time that are recommended for a race.   Other than that, the course committee sets the course.  I was unable to find the specific times for each class.   This means the course distance will depend on the expected wind.  In fact, although discouraged, the lengths can be adjusted during the race if the wind changes significantly.
There's a large amount of information for Race Management at https://www.sailing.org/tools/documents/RaceManagementManualJuly2019-%5B25256%5D.pdf, including course details in sections J and L.
The policy document (https://d7qh6ksdplczd.cloudfront.net/sailing/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/23131724/WS-Race-Management-Policies-Fleet-Racing-January-2024.pdf) also has some information on course setup.
